# Can't recognize dtype int as int in computation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns (serverTs, FTs) in DataFrame which are timestamps in the format of Unix Time.
In my code I need to subtract one from another. When i did so I received an error saying I can't subtract strings. So I added types for serverTs and FTs as integers.

```
file = r'S:\Работа с клиентами\Клиенты\BigTV Rating\fts_check.csv'
col_names = ["Day", "vcId", "FTs", "serverTs", "locHost", "tnsTmsec", "Hits", "Uniqs"]
df_empty = pd.DataFrame()
with open(file) as fl:
    chunk_iter = pd.read_csv(fl, sep='\t', names=col_names, dtype={'serverTs': np.int32, 'FTs': np.int32}, chunksize = 100000)
    for chunk in chunk_iter:
        chunk['diff'] = np.array(chunk['serverTs'])-np.array(chunk['FTs'])
        chunk = chunk[chunk['diff'] > 180]
        df_empty = pd.concat([df_empty,chunk])
```

But the program gives me an error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last) pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('int32')
>   according to the rule 'safe'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         6     #dtype={'serverTs': np.int32, 'FTs': np.int32},
>         7     #chunk_iter = chunk_iter.astype({'serverTs': np.int32, 'FTs': np.int32})
>   ----> 8     for chunk in chunk_iter:
>         9         #print(chunk[chunk['FTs'] == 'NaN'])
>        10         #chunk[['serverTs','FTs']] = chunk[['serverTs','FTs']].astype('int32')
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   **next**(self)    1040     def **next**(self):    1041         try:
>   -> 1042             return self.get_chunk()    1043         except StopIteration:    1044             self.close()
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   get_chunk(self, size)    1104                 raise StopIteration
>   1105             size = min(size, self.nrows - self._currow)
>   -> 1106         return self.read(nrows=size)    1107     1108
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   read(self, nrows)    1067                 raise ValueError('skipfooter
>   not supported for iteration')    1068 
>   -> 1069         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)    1070     1071         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   read(self, nrows)    1837     def read(self, nrows=None):    1838
>   try:
>   -> 1839             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    1840         except StopIteration:    1841             if self._first_chunk:
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'FTs'

I'm taking data from Hadoop with SQL queries, so I checked for any symbol with letters, but there are only numbers. Moreover if FTs has any characters which are not numbers it cannot appear in the database.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Does your CSV have a header? If it does, then do not pass `names` and let `read_csv` read the column names. It looks like you are trying to read the string `'FTs'` from the file as a number.

Comment: @jdehesa, yes, that was the problem. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are passing a `names` along with a `dtypes` argument. This causes `header` to act as `None`. So consider:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd, numpy as np

In [2]: dt={'serverTs': np.int32, 'FTs': np.int32}

In [3]: import io

In [4]: s = """FTs,serverTs
   ...: 0,1
   ...: 1,2
   ...: """

In [5]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))
Out[5]:
   FTs  serverTs
0    0         1
1    1         2

In [6]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), dtype=dt)
Out[6]:
   FTs  serverTs
0    0         1
1    1         2
```

Works fine. However, if I pass `names`:

```
In [8]: names = 'FTs','serverTs'

In [9]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), dtype=dt, names=names)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-18dcd5477b7e> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), dtype=dt, names=names)

/Users/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

/Users/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    453
    454     try:
--> 455         data = parser.read(nrows)
    456     finally:
    457         parser.close()

/Users/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1067                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1068
-> 1069         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1070
   1071         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

/Users/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1837     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1838         try:
-> 1839             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1840         except StopIteration:
   1841             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'FTs'

In [10]:
```

So one solution is to pass the correct header index:

```
In [10]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), dtype=dt, names=names, header=0)
Out[10]:
   FTs  serverTs
0    0         1
1    1         2
```

Or better yet, don't pass the `names` at all, `pandas` will infer it for you anyway:

```
In [11]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), dtype=dt)
Out[11]:
   FTs  serverTs
0    0         1
1    1         2
```

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga, thank you for the answer! I don't have any headers in this file, can I set dtype via column index somehow?

Comment: @YuliaPerunovskaia can you provide the first 5 lines or so of your `.csv` file?

Comment: sorry, I've checked the head of the file, and I actually do have headers. Now I see what made the error to appear. The code is still running, but it seems like the problem is solved, I receive no errors. Thank you a lot!